# posting back with a textbox vs label

Tags: c#

Here is my code -

```
dtDetails = getDataSet();

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows) {

    int rowID = 1;
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    {
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbJanuary" + rowID;

        tb.Text = dr["Jan"].ToString();

        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    rowID ++;
}
```

When this initially runs, I get correct values within my textboxes.

However, when I update a value in the database through a button click on the page, it causes the expected PostBack. When I come back into this loop, dr["Jan"].ToString() has the new correct value base don that change, but the textbox on the oage never gets updated.

If I change the code to this -

```
dtDetails = getDataSet();

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows) {

    int rowID = 1;
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    {
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "lblJanuary" + rowID;

        lbl.Text = dr["Jan"].ToString();

        cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    rowID ++;
}
```

the label contains the correct new value.

What is it about the text box that doesn't display the correct value?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `GridView`? Managing dynamic controls is rather painful generally.

Comment: Long story. I prefer to use this approach as it works better for my AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are never incrementing the `int` variable `rowID` which you use to generate the ID for the `Label`.

So i assume that this causes the `ViewState` to not work properly.

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows) {

    int rowID = 1;
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    {
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbJanuary" + rowID++;

        tb.Text = dr["Jan"].ToString();

        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

Apat from that, i would strongly recommend to use a GridView or another [`DataBound control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx), because otherwise you need to recreate each dynamically created control on postback with the same ID as before.

Comment: I actually do increment rowID, just forgot to put it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 2.0 had a design change by which the `Textbox` control marked with its `ReadOnly` property as `true`, would ignore client side changes and would lose the same across postback.If you want that functionality instead of making the textbox readonly using properties option. Add the code:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

In codebehind which will still make the textbox as  readonly and will also retain the value after each postback

So,your code should be like this:

```
dtDetails = getDataSet();

foreach (DataRow dr in dtDetails.Rows) {

    int rowID = 1;
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    {
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();

        tb.ID = "tbJanuary" + rowID;

        tb.Text = dr["Jan"].ToString();
        tb .Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
}
```